# How to redirect to an other webpage onclicking on input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an input of type button:

```
<input type='button' value='Click me' />
```

I need to redirect on clicking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it need to do anything other than redirect? Does any form data need to get transferred?  Or is this just a button that should be a link?

Comment: no, it's a button coz the design is based on buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html:

```
 <input type='button' id="myBtn" value='Click me' />
```

js:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
btn.onclick = function(){
   window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
}
```

don't forget the `window.onload`

Answer (score 3):

Option 1:

Use a link tag instead

```
<a href="other_site">Click Me</a>
```

And make the element look button-like via CSS.

Option 2:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" 
       onclick="window.location='http://www.example.org';" />
```